# Howto create same style of tMenuItem with AdvancedDrawItem?

Tags: delphi, styles, vcl, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tmenuitem

I would like to add a Line with a specific color for each MenuItem of popup menu in Tokyo VCL app. The Style is "Amethyst Kamri".

I'm invoked the AdvancedDrawItem event of each MenuItem as below. However, the hilighted box is flat and has not the same 3d shape as the non-ownerdraw look.

The flat background (in Orange):
[image]
While I would like to get it:
[image]
Howto implement it better? Delphi 10.2, VCL.

```
procedure TForm1.mnuColorAdvancedDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  MenuItem : tMenuItem;
  LStyles  : TCustomStyleServices;
  LDetails : TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  MenuItem := (Sender as TMenuItem);
  LStyles  := StyleServices;

  ACanvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;

  ACanvas.Font.Color  := LStyles.GetStyleFontColor(sfPopupMenuItemTextNormal);

  //check the state
  if odSelected in State then
    begin
      ACanvas.Brush.Color := LStyles.GetSystemColor(clHighlight);
      ACanvas.Font.Color  := LStyles.GetSystemColor(clHighlightText);
    end;

  ACanvas.FillRect(ARect);
  ARect.Left := ARect.Left + 2;
  //draw the text
  ACanvas.TextOut(ARect.Left + 2, ARect.Top, MenuItem.Caption);

end;
```

Thanks
Reron

Comment: Maybe you could add image snip to your question for accurate indication of what you want and what you currently get (it may not become visible immediately, but somebody here with sifficient reps will enable the image). Are you using standard Windows style, or any of the special styles that comes with Delphi?

Comment: Hi Tom, The Style is "Amethyst Kamri", but it happen with others. I Don't know how to capture a popup window. With my code, the background of the selected item is just a uniform orange colour rectangle, while the non-OwnerDraw has a frame around it and I think some kind of gradient Orange rectangle.

Comment: With the **Windows Snipping Tool** you can take images of menus (also with an item hovered on). Look in the help: *To capture a snip of a menu*

Comment: Thanks Tom, I like it!. My fault in the code was using FillRect. However my fight for implement a pop up item with style and Check box with AdvancedDrawItem is still open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I more or less find a solution. The problem was using Canvas FillRect.
Assume three PopUp menu items, Red, Green and Blue. The line color for each of them is stored in each Tag field. Each Menu-line is composed from three elements: A Check mark, a Color line and the Caption.
All three items have a common event ColorAdvancedDrawItem.

All Owner draw methods are based on Styles and not on direct Canvas drawing, except the new lines. See code:

```
procedure TForm1.ColorAdvancedDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
const
  CheckBoxWidth = 20;
  LineLen       = 25;
var
  MenuItem : tMenuItem;
  LStyles  : TCustomStyleServices;
  LDetails : TThemedElementDetails;
  CheckBoxRect, LineRect, TextRect: TRect;
  Y: integer;
begin
  MenuItem := (Sender as TMenuItem);
  LStyles  := StyleServices;

  // Draw Check box
  if MenuItem.Checked then
    begin
      LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tmPopupCheckNormal);
      CheckBoxRect := ARect;
      CheckBoxRect.Width := CheckBoxWidth;
      LStyles.DrawElement(ACanvas.Handle, LDetails, CheckBoxRect);
    end;

  // Draw text
  // Check the state
  if odSelected in State then
    LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tmPopupItemHot)
  else
    LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tmPopupItemNormal);

  TextRect      := ARect;
  TextRect.Left := CheckBoxWidth + LineLen;
  LStyles.DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, LDetails, MenuItem.Caption, TextRect, [tfLeft, tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter]);

  // Draw Line
  ACanvas.Pen.Color := tColor(MenuItem.Tag);
  ACanvas.Pen.Width := 2;
  LineRect := ARect;
  LineRect.Left := CheckBoxWidth;
  LineRect.Width:= LineLen;
  Y := LineRect.Top + (LineRect.Height div 2);
  ACanvas.MoveTo(LineRect.Left+2, Y);
  ACanvas.LineTo(LineRect.Left + LineRect.Width - 2, Y);
end;
```

The results looks like: [image]